# How to store JWT Token in DB with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

We use JWT Token with Django REST Framework.
Where store JWT Token and I want to store JWT Token in my DB. Because I used this API for mobile app.

Here create JWT Token

```
class LoginView(APIView):
     permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a Valid token if username and password
        is valid for a given client
        """
        try:
            username = request.data['username']
            password = request.data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
                    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

                    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                    token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

                    ind = Individual.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).first()
                    ind.login_flag = True
                    ind.save()
```

here, I used JWT Token Verification

```
class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        .......
        .......
```

Its working proper with JWT Token verification on postman. But I want to where store token and How to store JWT Token in my DB.

Comment: Storing JWT token in database is not a proper way as there will always be an expiry time set for each token we have created for a logged-in user. We only need to keep track of the logged-in user and his device-id.

Answer (score 3):

As others on this thread already suggested, the major point is not storing JWT in your database. It is meant for stateless authentication. You should be able to generate and retrieve the tokens using a secret.

One way to accomplish this in Django is using the `SECRET_KEY` to encode and decode the data in JWT like:

```
import jwt

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from your_project import custom_exceptions as exc


def get_token_for_user(user, scope):
    """
    Generate a new signed token containing
    a specified user limited for a scope (identified as a string).
    """
    data = {
        "user_%s_id" % (scope): str(user.id),
    }
    return jwt.encode(data, settings.SECRET_KEY).decode()


def get_user_for_token(token, scope):
    """
    Given a selfcontained token and a scope try to parse and
    unsign it.

    If max_age is specified it checks token expiration.

    If token passes a validation, returns
    a user instance corresponding with user_id stored
    in the incoming token.
    """
    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
    except jwt.DecodeError:
        raise exc.NotAuthenticated("Invalid token")

    model_cls = get_user_model()

    try:
        user = model_cls.objects.get(pk=data["user_%s_id" % (scope)])
    except (model_cls.DoesNotExist, KeyError):
        raise exc.NotAuthenticated("Invalid token")
    else:
        return user
```

The function `get_token_for_user` would bind the `user_id` and `scope` of the token together and encode it using the secret key. One might be able to only decode it if the `SECRET_KEY` is known.

`get_token_for_user` & `get_user_for_token` are the utility function you can use once you get the Token from your `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header to verify if the token is successfully decoded and valid.

These utility function also support a `scope` for each token you create. So, for example, you can say that this particular token is just for `authentication` and mention the scope as `authentication`.

The `scope` parameter accepted by these utility function is just a string, so you can use whatever scope you can think of, and while decoding it for a particular API call, you know what scope the token should be available in.

You can modify these as you desire to support JWT for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

As @Vijesh mentioned in his comment, storing JWT token is not the right approach. From the DRF documentation,

> Unlike the built-in TokenAuthentication scheme, JWT Authentication
>   doesn't need to use a database to validate a token.

Since you are using [django-rest-framework-jwt](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) package for the JWT token authentication. You can also use its apis for retrieving or refreshing the token.

In scenarios where username & password cannot be provided for retrieving or refreshing one should use protected url with JWT token in Authorization header. So after login, construct Authorization header with the token received. (note don't miss the JWT part in the header)

```
Authorization: JWT <your_token>
```

Curl Sample

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/
```

Comment: i was used same documentation. its working good, But token store in session and when I using this api for mobile app then its not working. Because on mobile not available session.

Comment: Did you used protected url ? In scenarios where username & password cannot be supplied, you should use protected url with JWT token in authorization header. So after your login, you should add token in the header for the protected Urls.   Authorization: JWT <your_token>

Answer (score 2):

A major point of using JWT is you don't want to store tokens in your database. Storing jwt will defeat the purpose of stateless authentication.

You just validate the token and cryptography takes care of the rest.The secret used to create, JWT verifies it against any hampering. Further, It is required that you implement jwt implementation over ssl, to avoid token hijacking.

You don't typically store any secure data in JWT, but you can if you want by  encrypting the payload. As mentioned in JWE specification.